# How to quickly solve $ \frac{x}{58.5} + \frac{0.118-x}{74.5} = \frac{0.2451}{143.5} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How do I quickly solve $ \frac{x}{58.5} + \frac{0.118-x}{74.5} = \frac{0.2451}{143.5} $ or a similar equation? I was actually doing chemistry questions for practice for JEE and while solving one of the questions I encountered this equation. This is only a part of the entire problem and I can't spend more than one or two minutes on this at the most. Trying to take the LCM is difficult and very time consuming. How do I solve this quickly without spending too much time on this? The answer I'm supposed to get is x = 0.0338.

Comment: Step one: Multiply both sides by $58.5 \times 74.5 \times 143.5$.
Step two: Group the $x$-terms together and move everything else to the right-hand side.
Step three: Divide by the factor of $x$.

Comment: Is a calculator disallowed ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, its disallowed

Comment: @Hema It's the JEE. Surely options must be given.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг its the JEE advanced actually, and this is an old question from the analytical and descriptive type, also this equation comes in the middle of the solution, the result is used in the next few steps.

Comment: @Hema Analytic and descriptive? Yes, then your issue is valid. What does the solution do? Because getting three digit precision in under two minutes only comes with practice.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг https://brainly.in/question/962422

Comment: @Hema Astonishing. That part takes up nearly eighty percent of the solving time of the question, and they have just written the answer without going into the steps. Personally, while none of the answers below are wrong, they do not cover how one can computationally get such precision in small time. For such a purpose, either I recommend Vedic mathematics, or I would ask you to skip such a question and keep it for the latter part of your examination, or for a time when you are in flow : it is a fairly monotone activity, so JEE is not really testing any ability of yours there.

Comment: @Hema On second thoughts, unless this question is worth more than the others (I don't recall the format for JEE advanced : I only saw the paper of 2013), I would recommend not attempting it at all, it is a waste of time.

Comment: @Hema If I were in your situation I would just leave it (mentioning that of course $x$ can be solved on base of the equation) and go further with expressions in $x$. The final answer will then be an expression of $x$ and it would be very very unfair if a correct expression in $x$ would not be rewarded. If that would happen after all then a protest is on its place (eventually accompanied with a link to your question here).

Answer (score 1):

We want a quick way to solve $\frac{x}{58.5} + \frac{0.118-x}{74.5} = \frac{0.2451}{143.5}$.

Since we want an answer with three significant digits we should round intermediate numbers to four or five significant digits and round the answer off to three.

We begin by separating out the $x$ terms:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{1}{58.5}-\frac{1}{74.5}\right)x+\frac{0.118}
{74.5}&=&\frac{0.2451}{143.5}\\
&&\\
\text{Convert to decimal notation}&&\\
&&\\
3.6712\times10^{-3}x+1.5839\times10^{-3}&=&1.7080\times10^{-3}\\
&&\\
\text{Multiply through by }10^{3}\text{ to get}&&\\
&&\\
3.6712x+1.5839&=&1.7088\\
&&\\
x&=&\frac{1.7088-1.5839}{3.6712}\\
&&\\
x&=&0.03380
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

This is easy.  For a start multiply the equation by 58.5 and then 74.5 to get: $$74.5x+58.5(0.118-x)=0.2451*58.5*74.5/143.5=7.444$$
This can be re-arranged to give: $$74.5x-58.5x+58.5*0.118=7.444$$

The next line will read: $$16x=7.444 - 6.903=0.541$$

That is, x = 0.0338